# Sub it in or use another way?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, tangent-line

Let's say there is a tangent: $y=3x^2+4x-5$

The given point is: $(1,2)$

And we need to find the gradient.

Should I sub $1$ and $2$ into $x$ and $y$ or should I use the quadratic function?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  You are given that y= 4x+ 9.  That is the equation of a straight line with gradient "4". The point (1, 2) is NOT on that line.

Comment: Oops It should be $3x^2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This thing is changing faster than I can type!  If the curve is given by $y= 3x^2+ 4x- 5$ then, since $y= 3(1^2)+ 4(1)- 5= 3+ 4- 5= 2$, yes, (1, 2) is on that curve.  The derivative is $y'= 6x+ 4$. At x= 1 the gradient of the curve is $y'= 6(1)+ 4= 10$.  The tangent line to the curve at x= 1 is y= 10x- 8.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Comment: So bacially I just need to use the derivative and sub $x$?

Comment: And sorry for the confusion

Comment: Yes, finding the derivative of the original function at $x$ to find the slope at the given point is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @KM101!